# Addressing fields in ArcGIS field calculator dynamically?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I am (re-)learning ArcGIS for a new job after couple of years on PostGIS (and QGIS/pyqgis) and can't figure out how I can address a Field within the pre-logic-block of the field calculator.

**Pre-Logic-Field:**

```
def createStyleField(kindofuse):
    if kindofuse == 'wa':
        listofrelevantfields= {
            1: ['level1', 'level1_wa'],
            2: ['level2', 'level2_wa']
        }
    elif kindofuse == 'ge':
        listofrelevantfields= {
            1: ['level1', 'level1_ge'],
            2: ['level2', 'level2_ge']
        }
    elif kindofuse == 'gi':
        listofrelevantfields= {
            1: ['level1', 'level1_gi'],
            2: ['level2', 'level2_gi']
        }
    results = {}
    for levelkuerzel, liste in listofrelevantfields.iteritems():
        for entry in liste:
            if '!' + entry + '!' == 1: ## THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO ADDRESS A FIELD
                results[levelkuerzel] = True
                break
            else:
                continue
    for i in range(1, 5) : #up to 5 levels, the lowest will be returned
        try:
            if results[i] == True:
                return unicode(i)
        except KeyError as err:
            continue
        except Exception as err:
            raise err
    return 0
```

And the other Field:

```
createStyleField('wa')
```

I need this for a couple of more complex calculations with a big number and case-dependent selection of fields. How do I do this?

Or should I address this issue totally different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this case by not addressing a field dynamically, but there are other cases where dynamically choosing of field come in handy...

Especially because it will be used later in an arcpy-script.

**Pre-Logic:**

```
def createStyleField(listofrelevantfields):
##    listofrelevantfields = {}
##    if kindofuse == 'wa':
##        listofrelevantfields= {
##            1: ['level1', 'level1_wa'],
##            2: ['level2', 'level2_wa']
##        }
##    elif kindofuse == 'ge':
##        listofrelevantfields= {
##            1: ['level1', 'level1_ge'],
##            2: ['level2', 'level2_ge']
##        }
##    elif kindofuse == 'gi':
##        listofrelevantfields= {
##            1: ['level1', 'level1_gi'],
##            2: ['level2', 'level2_gi']
##        }
    results = {}
    for levelkuerzel, liste in listofrelevantfields.iteritems():
        for entry in liste:
##            if '!' + entry + '!' == 1:
            if entry == 1:
                results[levelkuerzel] = True
                break
            else:
                continue
    for i in range(1, 5) :
        try:
            if results[i] == True:
                return unicode(i)
        except KeyError as err:
            pass
        except Exception as err:
            raise err
    return 0
```

**Calling it:**

```
createStyleField({1: [!level1!, !level1_wa!], 2: [!level2!, !level2_wa!]})
```